# Package management for bitbucket?

Tags: package, bitbucket

On github, if you look at any organization(like [node](https://github.com/nodejs) for example), there is Packages tab. Here we can manage packages like nuget, npm etc that we may produce in our repos.

[image: Packages Tab on github]

Here is how it looks when that tab is clicked.

[image: The packages tab on github]

So the question is, **is there anything like that offered by bitbucket**? I am not able to find anything here. Am I missing something trivial?

[image: where is bitbucket package management]

Of course on Azure DevOps, we have artifacts which I have used in the past.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As of today, BitBucket does not offer something like GitHub Packages or Azure Artifacts. You can upvote the feature request [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-19547).

You can also consider using a standalone product like [ProGet](https://inedo.com/proget).

Comment: For the record, as of late October 2023, this is still not supported.